# Can you concatenate one string onto two variables in one line?

Tags: php

Originally, I only had the need to build up a single MySQL query string with a chain of ternary operations.

```php
(isset($jsonData->type)) ? $whereStr .= " AND `ACCIDENT_TYPE` IN (:ctype)" : false;
```

This would then be appended to `$queryStr` before running `$query = $readDB->prepare($queryStr)`. And for a time, this was good. But then I found myself needing to use `LEFT JOIN` and could no longer keep all of my `WHERE` clause in one string since I now needed to use separate `ON` clauses instead of a single `WHERE` clause.

At first, I thought I'd see what would happen if I tried this:

```php
(isset($jsonData->type)) ? $whereStr .= $accidentOnStr .= " AND `ACCIDENT_TYPE` IN (:ctype)" : false;
```

As you can imagine, this did not work. The `$whereStr` would end up with repeated values due to how the `.` operator works.

Are there any other ways I could build up two separate string variables sharing the same sub-string in a single line? Or am I forced to use multi-line `if` statements to achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd rather write `isset($jsonData->type)) ? $whereStr .= " AND \`ACCIDENT_TYPE\` IN (:ctype)" : false;` than `if (isset($jsonData->type))) $whereStr .= " AND \`ACCIDENT_TYPE\` IN (:ctype)";`

Comment: Personal preference. I like being able to immediately read the variable in question without the `if` at the front. And since the `false` sits at the very end, it's not really in my way. I don't know if there is a difference, performance wise. I presume the ternary operation is slightly slower in this case, but I'm not too concerned about a millisecond here or there in this code.

Comment: Thanks - always interesting to understand other's coding style. In terms of your actual question, I'm pretty sure the answer is not without doing something hacky like [this](https://3v4l.org/lL7fr)

Comment: You call it hacky, I call it impressive. Well done! You should post it as an answer. It's technically correct. I have it on good authority that "technically correct" is the best kind of correct.

I did realise there's a simpler solution to my problem. By design, my `$whereStr` will always be the concatenation of all of my other `$accidentOnStr` type variables. So I can just build up the `$queryStr` with `"SELECT ... {$accidentOnStr} {$personOnStr}` etc. So I don't need the `$whereStr` at all!

Comment: Well, not needing `$whereStr` definitely makes life a lot easier. I've posted an answer, someone might find it useful one day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (hacky) way you could do what you want is to use `array_map` to add the string to each of the variables, passing it an array of references to the variables. For example:

```
$a = 'a string';
$b = 'b string';
$c = true;
$c ? array_map(function (&$v) { $v .= " c string";}, [&$a, &$b]) : false;
echo "$a\n$b\n";
```

Output:

```
a string c string
b string c string
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/lL7fr)